# How to show horizontal scrolling in ngb-tabset?

Tags: bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap, angular8

I want to show right-forward or left-back buttons, such as paging in mobile view or long tab display. Just like the material-tab.

```
 <ngb-tabset>
      <ngb-tab title="TAB-1">
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
          <p>TAB-1</p>
        </ng-template>
      </ngb-tab>
      <ngb-tab>
        <ng-template ngbTabTitle>TAB-2</ng-template>
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>Food truck fixie locavore, accusamus mcsweeney's marfa nulla single-origin coffee
          squid.
          <p>TAB-2</p>
        </ng-template>
      </ngb-tab>
      <ngb-tab title="TAB-3">
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
          <p>TAB-3</p>
        </ng-template>
      </ngb-tab>
      <ngb-tab title="TAB-4">
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
          <p>TAB-4</p>
        </ng-template>
      </ngb-tab>
    </ngb-tabset>
```

Comment: There's no support for that in Bootstrap, and thus in ng-bootstrap, which relies on Bootstrap.

Comment: Well, I need a feature like this. Then should I use material?